# Removing an object from a structure C++

Tags: c++, class, struct, containers

I ran into a little problem. I was trying to look through a structure, find an object that did not meet my requirements, and delete it.

But I get a "program stopped working" after executing the method.. Can you guys help?

```
void myStruct::ObRemove(int n)
{

for (myStruct *d = p; d != NULL; d = d->sek){
    if (d->m < n){
        ;
    }
    else{
        myStruct *m=d;
        d = m->sek;
        delete m;

    }
  }
}
```

the m is an object of a class, and this structure is a containter struct. If you need any additional code do tell, i'm waiting right here.

This is the structure class(NOTE: the names aren't similar as I was trying to make it in english, but rewriting will take so I paste it in my lang.)

```
 struct Mazgas
{
private:
Muziejus m;
Mazgas *sek;
Mazgas *p;
Mazgas *d;
public:
Mazgas() : p(NULL), d(NULL) {}
~Mazgas() { Naikinti(); }
void Naikinti();
void Deti(Muziejus m);
void Imti(Muziejus &m)
{
    m = d->m;
};
void Rikiuoti();
void Salinti(int n);
void Pradzia(){ d = p; }
void Sekantis() { if (d) d = d->sek; }
bool Yra() { return d != NULL; }
};
```

Comment: Post the code for 'myStruct'

Comment: At least these things we do not know, so how should we reason about what they do and what values they have? `myStruct`, `p`, `sek`

Answer (score 4):

In the else case, you are moving to the next item in the linked list twice (once via `d = m->sek;`, and once via `d = d->sek`). This can lead to an issue when you reach the end of the linked list (if `m->sek` is `NULL`, then `d->sek` will try to dereference `NULL`).

Comment: Yes, but the      d=d->sek is so that the loop would run. Isn't it?

Comment: @Mantas : that's why you put it there yes. But you should move to the next node only once in each iteration. A quick fix would be to move `d = d->sek` into the if block, and leave the for loop as `for (myStruct *d = p; d != NULL; )`.

Comment: @Mantas : time to get out your debugger then